# Short story about a cop who chases criminals in a dystopia where everyone is perfect at their job

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

Read at least ten years ago in an anthology, possibly *Writers of the Future*, but no idea which issue/edition. Everyone in the story is too good at their jobs, and so work is sort of hard to find, so firemen will engineer fires and other such stuff. A cop has a criminal in his squad car and comments on the growing chaos at the scene around him until eventually everyone dies and it’s revealed to have been the work of the Morticians all along.

What the heck is the name of this, and who wrote it?

Comment: What does it mean, that the cops and the robbers are both "perfect at their jobs"? The cops catch the robbers, or the robbers get away? In a professional baseball game, does the pitcher strike out every batter, or does every batter hit a home run?

Comment: A quick look on Google Books reveals no "writers of the future" books with the word "mortician" or "undertaker". It's possible the word was mis-transcribed, but it seems more likely that this isn't the correct anthology series

Comment: @user14111 I think I've read this and it's a spoof. Homes are so well built that they don't catch fire, so the firemen set fires to justify their employment. Likewise health care is so good that no-one is dying so the undertakers/morticians engineer a riot to give them corpses to process.

Comment: @JohnRennie that’s definitely the one, any idea what it’s called?

Comment: @Vik I have ransacked my short story collection and I cannot find the story, so it must have been something I read in a library book. I have been beating my head against the wall in the hope of shaking the memory loose, but so far with no luck :-(